# Extending use of NPSP Address__c object

Tags: relationships, npsp, address

The `npsp__Address__c` object in the Nonprofit Success Pack is a great way of succinctly tracking an Address.  It even comes with some features for validation and geocoding.

The down side is that out of the box, `npsp__Address__c` has a Master-Detail relationship to an Account (`npsp__Address__c.npsp__Household_Account__c`) and a one-to-many relationship to Contact (`Contact.npsp__Current_Address__c`).

I have some other objects that would need address records (notably Case).  My current plan is to basically redo the `npsp__Address__c` infrastructure (in a `Case_Address__c` object), but I wonder if it would make sense to extend `npsp__Address__c` - that is, remove the "required" property on `npsp__Household_Account__c` in the layout, and create a field on case called `Case.Address__r`.

Has anyone extended `npsp__Address__c` beyond its intended use?  How well does it work?

Comment: I highly recommend you ask this in the Hub. That's where you're going to get answer from people who work with the NPSP at this level. I'd strongly advise against redoing the infrastructure of the npsp__Address__c. Extending it would be the only way to go. You don't want to destroy your Household relationship, nor the relationship with Contacts.

Comment: @crmprogdev Clarified the scope of the Address "redo" - it's just recreating the functionality elsewhere, not replacing it in place.

Comment: Can't you just create a lookup to a Case in npsp__Current_Address__c object? At the end of the day, a case will be linked to an account, you will just need to always populate npsp__Address__c.npsp__Household_Account__c it's a M-D relationship